# Defining submanifolds without charts

Tags: smooth-manifolds

In his elegant 2012 introduction to smooth manifolds, Nigel Hitchen minimizes his reliance on charts.
In stating what it means for a manifold $M$ to be a smooth submanifold of $N$,
for example, he gives the condintion
that $D\iota_x$ is injective for all $x\in M$. For me, at least, it would be easier to digest a condition
that for any smooth function on $N$ its restriction to $M$ is smooth, but am I correct in inferring that
the two conditions are equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

As a good reference for embedded vs immersed submanifolds check the book of Frank Warner -- Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups. where a lot of subtleties are discussed.